# Is there any way to replace old text with new text through typewriter effect and making it come back in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Here's my current code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Typewriter effect</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="first-text">Hello!</h1>
        <h1 class="second-text">How are you?</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically I want to replace the first text with the second text after 2 seconds, and then go back to the first text after 2 seconds. Is there any way to do that in CSS?

Every tutorial I found online were about having 2 sets of text, where one would be the same every time, and the other would be changing constantly.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Typewriter effect</title>
    <style>
        .container {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .text-animation {
            display: inline-block;
            opacity: 0;
            animation: switchText 4s linear infinite;
        }

        @keyframes switchText {
            0%, 20% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
            25%, 100% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
        }

        .text-animation:nth-child(2) {
            animation-delay: 2s; /* Delay for the second text to start */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-animation">Hello!</h1>
        <h1 class="text-animation">How are you?</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is it possible to do it in such a manner where the first text and the second texts are overlapping each other and the second text doesn't show up until the first text disappears completely?

Comment: Yes Possible! Edited answer please check.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thanks so much! I'm new to CSS so this helped me out a lot.